# Can I mount an Azure Storage account to my Azure Website as a drive letter?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have a PHP application that I cannot modify, and part of this application accepts uploads from the end-user. I don't want to store those uploads (which could be large) to my Azure Website storage allocation, so I would rather direct them to an Azure Storage account. Is there some way to mount an Azure Storage account to my Website as a simple drive letter so I can save files to it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure Web Sites don't allow you to do this at the moment. You could evaluate other options:

- Use a Virtual Machine with a Data Disk (persisted in Blob Storage, but hard to scale since only 1 instance can mount a specific VHD in Blob Storage)
- Use a Web/Worker Role with the [Azure Drive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee924681.aspx) (persisted in Blob Storage, but hard to scale since only 1 instance can mount a specific VHD in Blob Storage)
- Use a Web/Worker Role or VM together with the [AzureBlobDrive](https://github.com/richorama/AzureBlobDrive). This allows you to 'mount' a storage account like a drive. This way your application will think it writes to a disk, while it's actually writing to blob storage.